# Batch will list files in a folder, ask me which one and when i choose it will open it

Tags: list, batch-file, cmd

All scripts that i looked were same, they are listing the files in a folder and asking me to choose. And when i press for example "3" nothing is happening. I want batch to LIST files in a folder, then ASKS me to choose one, and the most important part: OPEN what i choosed

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set count=0
set "choice_options="

for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /a:-d /b C:\image\Aselsan\') do (
    REM Increment %count% here so that it doesn't get incremented later
    set /a count+=1

    REM Add the file name to the options array
    set "options[!count!]=%%A"

    REM Add the new option to the list of existing options
    set choice_options=!choice_options!!count!

)

for /L %%A in (1,1,!count!) do echo [%%A]. !options[%%A]!
choice /c:!choice_options! /n /m "Enter a file to load: "

cmd /k
```

Please help me to OPEN that text file, im stuck.. Thanks for every help

Comment: You need to add something for it to do when the choice is made! I'd suggest you put that somewhere between line `20` and line `22`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a line:

```
start C:\image\Aselsan\!options[%ERRORLEVEL%]!
```

in full:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set count=0
set "choice_options="

for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /a:-d  /b "C:\image\Aselsan\"') do (
    REM Increment %count% here so that it doesn't get incremented later
    set /a count+=1

    REM Add the file name to the options array
    set "options[!count!]=%%A"

    REM Add the new option to the list of existing options
    set choice_options=!choice_options!!count!
)

for /L %%A in (1,1,!count!) do (
    echo [%%A]. !options[%%A]!
    echo %%A
   
)

choice /c:!choice_options!  /m "Enter a file to load: "

start C:\image\Aselsan\!options[%ERRORLEVEL%]!

cmd /k
```

Comment: Omg thank you A LOT. It worked im really grateful.Can i ask some explanation about what is !options[%ERRORLEVEL%]!

Comment: For example, if you have three files a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg in a directory C:\image\Aselsan\

!options[%%A]! in the for loop is an array of file names contained in this directory with corresponding indices: `[1]. a.jpg [2]. b.jpg [3]. c.jpg`

The choice  command sets ERRORLEVEL environment variable to the index of the key that the user selects from the list of choices (according to the Microsoft documentation).

Let's say I select file b.jpg by typing 2, then
ERRORLEVEL is set to 2.
it expands to `start C:\image\Aselsan\!options[2]!`
it works because 2 is the index of the file b.jpg

Comment: Thanks a lot <33

Comment: hi can you help this?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65194566/batch-file-choice-command-more-than-10-parameter

Comment: Hi, it looks like I am late,  Stephan has already answered this question.

Comment: no reason to not add another answer, when it's better or different `;)`

Comment: I think your solution is pretty cool; I'm saving your answer to my private gists.  :)

Comment: It's creating a file named "0". It would be better if you save it after we fix this problem ( asked it now )